# What would be best option to publish Google Bigquery records of 10 million records to pubsub topic

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-pubsub

My requirement is to publish records of bigquery 10 million records to pubsub topic. Large time is not constraint.

havent trired anything, looking for suggestions

Comment: Create a dataflow for it.

Comment: Let explain full scenarios we are trying, we have bigquery views with millions of data which need to pushed to another table1 by applying joins and dynamic datarange on views. This we achieved using batch dataflow.After results are available in table1 we need to publish to pubsub based on some conditions. Dataflow to publish to pubsub needs streaming. we are not able to combine both batch and streaming in single dataflow.

Comment: we dont want to go with two dataflows/templates.

Comment: Why not? It's the best tool for the job. Write a simple Dataflow pipeline (batch) that reads your table from BigQuery and writes each row to Pub/Sub.

Comment: Just use this, and change the source from GCS to be your BigQuery table: https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/provided-batch#gcstexttocloudpubsub